# Angular Strap typeahead results with angle brackets

Tags: angularjs, typeahead, angular-strap, html-escape-characters

My results have legit brackets and they show up fine. 
But when I close brackets, the input value wiped clean of anything inside the brackets.

```
Typing "frank" returns:
frank<hotdog>
frankenstein

Typing "frank<hotdog" returns:
frank<hotdog>

Typing "frank<hotdog>" wipes out my input and replaces it with "frank" then returns:
frank<hotdog>
frankenstein
```

Comment: using angular-strap version 2.3.5.
I just removed this line in the library to override it. But hopefully there is a fix later.

`var value = selected ? selected.toString().replace(/<(?:.|\n)*?>/gm, '') : '';`

Comment: You can answer your own question and mark it as accepted - I guess there is plenty of future visitors that could take benefit of your solution ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using angular-strap version 2.3.5. I just removed this line in the library to override it. But hopefully there is a fix later. var value = selected ? selected.toString().replace(/<(?:.|\n)*?>/gm, '') : '';